# Disable Rails SQL logging in console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, console

Is there a way to disable SQL query logging when I'm executing commands in the console? Ideally, it would be great if I can just disable it and re-enable it with a command in the console.

I'm trying to debug something and using "puts" to print out some relevant data. However, the sql query output is making it hard to read.

---

**Edit:**
I found another solution, since setting the logger to nil sometimes raised an error, if something other than my code tried to call logger.warn

Instead of setting the logger to `nil` you can set the level of the logger to `1`.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1 # or Logger::INFO
```

Comment: `since setting the logger to nil sometimes raised an error` yap.. I got this one when trying to run `rake db:migrate`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719212/undefined-method-info-for-nilnilclass-when-running-active-record-migration

Comment: Confirming that this works in Rails 4.1.0 in an initializer.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

To turn it off:

```
old_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

To turn it back on:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = old_logger
```

Comment: Is there anywhere I can put this so I disable the SQL output permanently? I tried adding it to envs/dev.rb but not luck.

Comment: @samvermette, you don't set it.  Just call it from the console before doing your work.

Comment: you can put this code in `.irbrc`, which is basically `.bashrc` for the Rails console. in fact you can do just about anything in `.irbrc` if you want, e.g., syntax coloring, history, edit code in vi and then execute it in the Rails console, etc. check my gem `utility_belt` if you're on Ruby 1.8 or the Ruby 1.9 port called `flyrb`

Comment: @giles bowkett: Actually, ```.irbrc```is like ```.bashrc``` but actually for your _ruby_ interactive commandline.  It's not a rails thing.  I imagine you'd probably get errors if you tried to reference rails classes when you were running irb outside of a rails environment.

Comment: @samvermette you can it in a config file. For example: `config/initializers/activerecord_logger.rb`

Comment: Just fyi for anyone: after setting `Base.logger`, I also had to run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.clear_reloadable_connections!`

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1` is a much better answer as it won't raise exceptions if you use .info and others.

Comment: I can't +1 this enough. I've came back to this answer so many time I wouldn't be able to count. For some reason I can't seem to remember the syntax correctly :) ... but the sure thing is that it's really helpful to have this answer, so thanks a lot @ryanbigg!

Comment: @ryan-- hey is it possible to turn of logging for a specific model ?

Comment: If you accidentaly ran this code (to turn it off) twice, thus also setting `old_logger` to `nil`, then you may create a new console logger with `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` when you want to turn it back on again.

Comment: dirty henry's approach is superior because if you have existing logger.debug statements they will all throw exceptions if you use the accepted answer

Answer (score 96):

This might not be a suitable solution for the console, but Rails has a method for this problem: [Logger#silence](http://apidock.com/rails/Logger/silence)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence do
  # the stuff you want to be silenced
end
```

Comment: Will work only for up to Rails 3: "DEPRECATION WARNING: silence is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.0"

Comment: @Kangur I'm on rails 4.2 and silence seems to work fine

Comment: @Kangur I can also confirm this approach works just fine on Rails 4.2

Comment: Works in Rails 5 and I see no warnings. This is the best answer IMO.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (silence is not defined). Rails 5.2.2

Comment: Works fine in Rails 6. Maybe it's just been moved around a bit?

Answer (score 83):

Here's a variation I consider somewhat cleaner, that still allows potential other logging from AR. In config/environments/development.rb :

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Rails.logger.clone
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
end
```

Comment: Odd, not for me, in Rails 3.0 or 3.1.  Why would your Rails.logger be nil in an after_initialize block, did you do something else to customize your Rails init stack, or did you forget the config.after_initialize ?

Comment: Works great in my Rails 3.1 app. Seemsl ike the nicest solution. +1

Comment: Doesn't work for me ... sets the level OK in the after_initialize block, but the level is back to 0 by the time the console is open. Strange. (I'm using Pry as a console replacement, is that why?)

Answer (score 28):

For Rails 4 you can put the following in an environment file:

```
# /config/environments/development.rb

config.active_record.logger = nil
```

Comment: That would only take effect in production, where logging is mostly surpressed anyway....

Comment: in rails 5 this doesn't work. If you're work in linux environment, the following will work:   config.active_record.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
not sure if the same goes with newer version like 6 and 7

Answer (score 16):

In case someone wants to **actually** knock out SQL statement logging (without changing logging level, and while keeping the logging from their AR models):

The line that writes to the log (in Rails 3.2.16, anyway) is the call to `debug` in `lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:50`.

That debug method is defined by `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber`.

So we can knock out the logging by overwriting it like so:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class LogSubscriber
    def debug(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good one. This works on SQL logging without affecting `Rails.logger.debug` statements.

Comment: Total noob here. Where exactly should we put this?

Comment: I keep it in lib/monkeypatch.rb and have rails pull it in with the following line in config/application.rb: `Dir.glob( "./lib/*.{rb}" ).each{ | file | require file }`. Keep in mind that monkeypatching is frowned upon by some. Probably shouldn't check this into your production code.

Comment: I used this as a starting point for my Rails / ActiveRecord 6 solution, which I've added as an answer here. This version didn't quite work because it actually suppressed a lot of other logs I wanted to see.

Answer (score 11):

I used this: `config.log_level = :info`
edit-in `config/environments/performance.rb`

Working great for me, rejecting SQL output, and show only rendering and important info.

Comment: I'm on rails 4.1.0 and it's worked fine for me. thanks

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, if put `config.log_level = :fatal` it basically disables output to production log file almost completely, this is what I need since there is a custom request logger in play

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 3.2 I'm doing something like this in config/environment/development.rb:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do
      ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new( Rails.root.join("log", "development.log") )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as an FYI, in Rails 2 you can do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence { <code you don't want to log goes here> }
```

Obviously the curly braces could be replaced with a `do end` block if you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I use activerecord 6.0.3.3 and I had to include `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence`

```rb
include ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence

ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence.silence do
    ## everything you want to silence
end
```

This however did not work with anything related to creating or deleting SQL tables like `ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table`. For this to be silenced I added:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve this for ActiveRecord 6, and I based my answer on `fakeleft`'s response, but it wasn't quite right, since it was suppressing other logging such as the logging of nested views. What I did was created `config/initializers/activerecord_logger.rb`:

```rb
# Suppress SQL statement logging if necessary
# This is a dirty, dirty trick, but it works:
if ENV["ACTIVERECORD_HIDE_SQL"].present?
  module ActiveRecord
    class LogSubscriber
      def sql(event)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The log subscriber in AR 6 has a `sql` event that we want to hide, so this is very narrowly targeted to skip *that* event.