# Why do ActiveRecord queries from console print sql statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, irb, rails-console, pry

I'm using pry, and ActiveRecord queries from the console always print out their corresponding SQL statements. I don't want this behavior. Googling around I only see that this must be explicitly achieved by setting the ActiveRecord logger to standard out.

Is this the default behavior of pry or is it the result of something I set that I forgot about? And how can I stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3.1+  this is now the default behaviour. Check here [Disable Rails SQL logging in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging)

Answer (score 6):

Try looking for a `.irbrc` file in the project root or your home directory. You may see this or similar:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Sometimes this ends up in another script that gets included in `.irbrc`.

YMMV, but I really like having SQL logged to the console. To each his own...

Comment: Pry does not use `.irbrc` it uses `.pryrc`