# Turn off verbose sql/ActiveRecord for Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Whereas the verbose feature of SQL/ActiveRecord calls is useful most of the time, I would like to turn it off in cases where I have some looping going on.

Is there a way to turn it off?

```
irb(main):055:0> City.first
  ←[1m←[35mCity Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` LIMIT 1
=> #<City id: 1, name: "bla bla", state_id: 1, zip: nil, country_id: nil,
created_at: "2011-03-27 14:11:28", updated_at: "2011-08-16 11:14:36", guid: "5PK
fvvz2Gsi">
```

Comment: Yep, you can turn it off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging

Answer (score 25):

In console:
Disable:

```
old_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

Enable:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = old_logger
```

Comment: Is there another way of doing this? This is causing errors in code that use logger.debug. I would like to turn off the ones I didn't manually write.

Comment: Another way of doing it, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging, is `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1` to turn the logging off (sets log level to info), and `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 0` to turn it back on (sets log level to debug).

Comment: @FloatingRock Only for this session (the current process), I'm 99.9% sure. Try it and report back :)

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4 I've been annoyed by ActiveRecord logging SQL statements in the middle of my specs so I disable it by adding this to `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... 
  config.log_level = :info
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place this code in your **rails_spec.rb** file.

```
  config.before do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
  end
```

It did the trick for me.