# rails with cucumber show unnecessary output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cucumber, tdd, rails-migrations

When I run `bundle exec cucumber` this line "ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"" is printed on the console.

Why is that? How can I get rid of it?

```
$ bundle exec cucumber
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
$
```

Comment: rails --version
Rails 4.2.5
 cucumber --version
2.3.3
ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: You need to tell what you want from a question. Also mark your solution as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was browsing around stack overflow, and today I
found a solution here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33987617/4394500

Basically, add

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... 
  config.log_level = :info
end
```

to `config/environments/test.rb`