# Rails - how to disable all console logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Coming from a javascript background, I find the command line while running rails to be cluttered. Every time something happens, my command line is filled with a bunch of crap. E.g:

```
[2013-06-19 20:25:53] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

How do I turn this off so that I only see my own logs(and errors, of course)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing the log level, which is info by default.

From the Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: I set it to `0`, and yet I still get warnings.

Comment: You need to set it to 4 or :fatal.  This will filtered out all lower level messages

Answer (score 7):

Change the log level in `config/environments/development.rb`, and/or `testing.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :error
```

The log levels available are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`, which correspond to the integers `0`-`5`.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the SQL queries. I know they take a lot of room.

[Disable Rails SQL logging in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging)

Comment: Although this is useful, I am looking to disable **all** of Rails' notifications/logs/whateveryouwanttocall them. So HTTP requests, warnings, everything but errors

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

> ./**.env**
>
> usually file **.env** is used to store all important / secret properties of your application environment. Create **.env** if not exist and add code:

```
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true
```

> ./config/environments/*.rb
>
> edit your environment file (e.g. ./config/environments/development.rb) to create a disconnectable logging system.

```
Rails.application.configure do

  # ...

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'] == 'true'
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    # To support a formatter, you must manually assign a formatter from the config.log_formatter value to the logger.
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter

    # config.logger is the logger that will be used for Rails.logger and any 
    # related Rails logging such as ActiveRecord::Base.logger.
    # It defaults to an instance of ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging that wraps an 
    # instance of ActiveSupport::Logger which outputs a log to the log/ directory.
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)

    # config.log_level defines the verbosity of the Rails logger. 
    # This option defaults to :debug for all environments. 
    # The available log levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, and :unknown
    #config.log_level = :debug

    # config.log_tags accepts a list of: methods that the request object responds to,
    # a Proc that accepts the request object, or something that responds to to_s. 
    # This makes it easy to tag log lines with debug information like subdomain and request id -
    # both very helpful in debugging multi-user production applications.
    config.log_tags = [:request_id]
  end
end
```

### Usage

set `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true` in **.env** to **turn on** console logger

delete or comment out line `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true`, or set `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=false` in **.env** to **turn off** console logger

[How to start Rails server with environment variables set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426702/how-to-start-rails-server-with-environment-variables-set/60141196#60141196)

### More info

[Configuring Rails Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)