# How to start Rails server with environment variables set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I have the following command. I insert it on starting the `rails server`

```
VARIABLE=development rails s
```

How do I make this variable start automatically, without having to wright it myself every time?

So I would then just do this

```
rails s
```

and it would run automatically with that variable.

Comment: Use dotenv gem https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: I fix your questions, and suggest your read [`Bash-Beginners-Guide`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various options to do so:

1. Declare your variables in `.bashrc` file and reload it.
2. Use [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem.
3. Use [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem.

More info @ http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/managing-environment-configuration-variables-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

Bundle the [dotenv-rails gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), then create a `.env` file with the content:

```
VARIABLE=development
```

The gem picks up all variables from the file and sets them in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

> **./.env**

```
APP_PORT=3000
APP_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV=development

DATABASE_NAME=batman
DATABASE_USER=bat
DATABASE_PASSWORD=1234
DATABASE_PORT=5443
```

> **./start.sh**
>
> script that will run your rails app with all variables from **./.env**

```
set -o allexport
source .env
set +o allexport
bundle exec rails s -p $APP_PORT -b $APP_HOST -e $ENV
```

[*set* command info](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)

> Do not forget to set access privileges to execute **./start.sh**

```
chmod +x ./start.sh
```

[*chmod* command info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

### Usage

> just run command from the root folder of your rails app:

```
./start.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the variable to be variating, you should put this into initializers or on a helper class.  If you're looking for enviroment, you don't need it because it's the default.