# Rails missing SECRET_KEY_BASE in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

I have ubuntu server, Rails 5.0 and apache web server
Also I have many sites on it

When I add new site, I have an error "Incomplete response received from application"

When I check apache log I see message:

```
App 14561 stderr: [ 2017-01-17 21:01:16.5804 14591/0x0000000064e100(Worker 1) utils.rb:85 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 14591, thread 0x0000000064e100(Worker 1)):
```

My config/secrets.yml contains default value:

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Also I have just setted env variable SECRET_KEY_BASE via writting in a file /etc/profile

I see than via command  `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`

How to fix error `Incomplete response received from application`

Comment: Read this about environment in rails http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `/etc/profile` is only sourced when invoking an interactive login shell, so any variables set in this file wouldn't ever get run by a web-server daemon on startup, which is why it didn't work as expected in your attempt.

Since you're using Apache + Phusion Passenger, you can set application-specific environment variables within your Apache configuration files using the [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) option of [`mod_env`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html).

Otherwise, you could set your environment variables from your application code by reading configuration on your application server's filesystem. You could use a gem like [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to automate this pattern.

See Phusion Passenger's documentation [About Environment Variables: Passenger-Served Apps](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html#passenger-served-apps) for a documentation reference.

Comment: I don't understand why only one site works well with standart `secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` at the same web server and ruby/rails configs
I have just checked using `SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE XXX ` at my available_sites/config and that helps

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your server, it might need to be restarted to pick up new changes in your `config` files.

Your config/secrets.yml file should also have:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Of course, I also have restarted my server many times, and after applying changes to secrets.yml file, application don't see my key in ENV ((

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are starting the server the ENV variables may not be visible.

Have you tried:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE='foo' rails s
```

Some discussion on environment variables with Rails servers is discussed at [How to start Rails server with environment variables set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426702/how-to-start-rails-server-with-environment-variables-set)

Comment: Because it's my production server, I use apache+ phusion passenger, download directory with my site via repository, that I have prepared at my development workplace. Than I configure apache config to load rails via passenger. Then I try command 'apachectl restart' and open my site. If there are any errors I check log files. So I use command `rails s ` only at development computer. Also direct specifying SECRET_KEY_BASE='XXX' at file secrets.yml solves my problem, but it's bad practic)

Comment: Agreed on the bad practice - but you could try this test just to validate whether the environment variables are being seen.  Of course in production you wouldn't want to have this setup due to the security risks

Answer (score 0):

### Check you have mod_env

```
sudo a2enmod env
```

### From your rails app [anywhere, does not matter, it's just a random string] run

```
rake secret
... outputs a big long string ...
```

### Then add to your Apache Virtual Host definition.

somewhere in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

```
<VirtualHost ...>
  SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE "thebiglongstringgeneratedbyrakesecret"
</VirtualHost>
```

### Check your work

```
apache2ctl -t
Syntax OK
```

### restart apache

```
apache2ctl restart
```

### check it from the command line

```
curl https://my-server-url -I # or http
```

Leave a comment if that does do the trick.