# Rails server exits as environment variable is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to rails, so please be considerate. I am trying to start rails server by the command 'rails s'(also tried 'bundle exec rails s' and RAILS_ENV=development rails s)and it exits with an error in a file which refers to an environment variable.

`/config/initializers/file_name.rb:7:in <class:FileName>: undefined method split for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

The line 7 in that file refers to an environment variable. Wondering how to make sure that the environment variables are loaded before I start my server. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something like this might come in handy https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: just to check if its really a missing environment variables: `MYVAR=value rails s` will set MYVAR when running rails server

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add gems to the app. Aren't env variables loaded by default in rails when we start the server?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky, thanks a lot. It has worked but wondering how we can overcome this situation if quite a few env variables are missing. How can we make sure the env variables are loaded by default?

Comment: Try this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426702/how-to-start-rails-server-with-environment-variables-set
basically, if you can't use a gem, you'll need to manually load your variables when starting the server, possibly build yourself a shell script which exports the variables and starts the server