# How to disable detailed console in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I use console for RoR and there is an error I get the list of gems/libs used, for example

```
SyntaxError: /Users/user/Sites/Jobsite/app/models/subject.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'
    where(["name LIKE ?"], "%#{query}%"])
                                        ^
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/Sites/Jobsite/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Do I really need this or can I disable it somehow, because each time I get this, I need to scroll up and I don't see the error message itself so easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the [log level](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels).

You can also turn off the SQL logging by putting this in an initializer:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

Maybe something like - `config/initializers/activerecord_logger.rb`

More info here - [Disable Rails SQL logging in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting `consider_all_requests_local` from `true` to `false` in `config/environments/development.rb` so it doesn't show the *stacktrace*:

```
Jobsite::Application.configure do
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
end
```