# How desactive messages of sqlite queries in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need that rails console not show me the sqlite query but only the response

```
2.0.0-p481 :002 > supplier.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.9ms)  INSERT INTO "suppliers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 13 Jul 2014 03:36:37 UTC +00:00], ["name", "aldo escudero"], ["updated_at", Sun, 13 Jul 2014 03:36:37 UTC +00:00]]
   (151.3ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.0.0-p481 :003 > Supplier.find(1)
  Supplier Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" WHERE "suppliers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Supplier id: 1, name: "pepe sanchez", created_at: "2014-07-13 03:36:37", updated_at: "2014-07-13 03:36:37"> 
2.0.0-p481 :004 >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Rails 3.1 SQL logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging)

Comment: Thank you Pavan . Can you respond my question for choose you the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/environments/development.rb, set:

```
config.log_level = :info
```