# Minitest output too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using `minitest-reporters` and `mini_backtrace` gems with the settings from the Hartl tutorial. The output of my tests are way too long. The output includes a lot of sql and also lists each test.

[image]

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging), the sql can be suppressed with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
```

but how do I suppress the listing of each test?  This is the output I'd like from the `minitest-reporters` gem's documentation:

[image]

How do I get a simple output like that?

Comment: Have you tried STDOUT redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Logger constants instead of arbitrary numbers: `Logger::INFO` for instance. Also, the ActiveRecord log shouldn't appear on STDOUT, but go into a log file. You may replace ActiceRecord::Base.logger with `Logger.new("log/test.log")` for example.

If you don't have the expected output from minitest-reporters, you'll may want to force the default reporter:

```rb
Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter
```

Comment: Julien, I updated my original question with an excerpt picture of my minitest output.  Assuming I haven't changed any defaults in Rails (I didn't think I did), is it supposed to be that long and include all of that information?  If not, what did I inadvertently change? I'd rather not change defaults (like ActiveRecord::Base.logger) if I don't have to.

Comment: I'm not sure why I had to add this line, but adding `config.log_level = :error` in `test.rb` fixed it.  Other repos which I've cloned don't have this line and have minimal testing output... so I'm not sure if what I've done differently.

Comment: I thought you were using AR without Rails.

Your actual problem is that something is messing your `Rails.logger`: all the logs should be going to `log/test.log` but they are instead pushed to STDOUT for some reason.

Try to remove the minitest-reporters and mini_backtrace and verify what happens then. Maybe loading them in another order in `test_helper.rb` like before or after Rails has loaded can resolve the issue.