# Unable to turn off SQL logging in my Rails production environment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-5, production

How do I turn off logging of SQL in my production Rails 5.0.1 environment?  I added this

```
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Rails.logger.clone
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
  end
```

to my config/environments/production.rb environment but I still see SQL logged in my log/production.log file.  Here is my complete production.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  config.cache_store = :memory_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  # Comment out the two lines withinn here so taht queries can be seen in the console
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Rails.logger.clone
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
  end

end
```

Comment: This answer has a few ideas you may want to look at... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-sql-logging-in-console

Comment: Per my file, I'm already doing those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-sql-logging-in-console) cited in comments, you need to add the following line to turn off SQL logging:
`ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil`

According to your posted config, you have `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO` instead. Replace this line with the one above and SQL logging will be disabled.

Additionally, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-sql-logging-in-console#comment32558260_7760140), you could use `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1` which will prevent exceptions caused by lesser levels of logs (ie: info, warn, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line in production.rb

```
config.active_record.logger = nil
```