# How to disable logging sql to particular query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I have found out from another SO Answer [Disable Rails SQL logging in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-sql-logging-in-console/13702204#13702204)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence do
  User.where(auth_token: request.headers['X-AUTH']).first
end
```

But the method seems to be deprecated. Is there any latest way to silence the logs for queries in a block?

Comment: What's the class of your `ActiveRecord::Base.logger`?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.logger.class
 => ActiveSupport::Logger

Comment: Huh - that docs for Rails 5.2 ([here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/LoggerSilence.html)) show `silence` being included with no mention of it being deprecated. What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Actually I am also not getting warning, but https://apidock.com/rails/Logger/silence showed deprecation. So I thought it's deprecated in 5.1 also. How do we know it's not deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're seeing [here](https://apidock.com/rails/Logger/silence) states:

> Method deprecated or moved

This looks like a case of *"or moved"* :)

Within the warning block it mentions the locations of similar methods, including `LoggerSilence#silence`.

That module contains a [silence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/LoggerSilence.html#method-i-silence) method and is now included in the [ActiveSupport::Logger](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html#method-c-logger_outputs_to-3F) class, which will handle it as you need.

Hope that helps here!

Comment: What did you decide upon @gates? Did this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 I use the following to prevent a query log of a token:

```
def authenticate_user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Rails.logger.info "Authenticating user..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Rails.logger.silence do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(token: token)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  end
end
```

I couple this with adding the token to:

config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb