# Turn off Cache model load statements in rails terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running rails in development and have lots of the following types of statements being logged when a page loads.

```
CACHE Land Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "lands".* FROM "lands" WHERE "lands"."farm_id" = $1  [["farm_id", 353]]
```

It is making debugging hard and is not letting me see things such as request params etc. Is it possible to get rid of this?

Comment: reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#caching-in-development

Comment: @LamPhan tried this, didn't work. Was already not being cached.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved easier debugging by following answers to this question:

[Disable Rails SQL logging in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-sql-logging-in-console)